# Separar uma string em php?

Tags: php

Tenho strings:

```
$str1 = "nome = stack";
$str1 = "id <5";
$str3 = "senha != over";
```

Como faço para pegar separar a string ali no operador ou no espaço (quando não tiver espaço seguido de operador ele irá separar no operador)? Nesse caso ficaria assim:

```
$str1 = "nome = "; //separou no espaço seguido de operador
$str1c = "stack";
$str2 = "id <"; //separou no operador
$str2c = "5";
$str3 = "senha != "; 
$str3c = "over";
```

Não coloquei código, pois não sei como iniciar.

Comment: O que seria um "operador" no caso? Seria qualquer sequência de caracteres não alfanuméricos e que também não é espaço em branco? Minha sugestão é usar regex, vou tentar montar um exemplo.

Comment: Seria < > ou =, estou quase conseguindo aqui depois de olhar a documentação do PHP, apenas quando tenho <= => etc (com dois caracteres) que não está dando certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php) junto com uma expressão regular. Esse método aceita uma flag que permite que o delimitador seja retornado também e incluído junto com os resultados (acho que ele precisa estar entre parênteses, pelo menos foi isso que eu entendi da documentação), de modo que você pode concatená-lo com a primeira parte para ter a divisão que quer:

```
$arr1 = preg_split("/([^\w\s]+\s*)/", $str1, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
echo $arr1[0] . $arr1[1] . "\n";
echo $arr1[2] . "\n";
```

[Exemplo no ideone](http://ideone.com/az0yWf). A expressão regular usada - `[^\w\s]+\s*` - pega qualquer sequência de caracteres que não é letra, dígito ou espaço, seguida opcionalmente de uma sequência de espaços em branco. O resultado é usado para dividir a string.

```
[     ]+     Um ou mais caracteres
 ^            que não são:
  \w           uma letra/número
    \s         ou um espaço
        \s*  Seguido de zero ou mais espaços
```

Nota: se sua string tiver dois ou mais operadores, o `preg_split` vai retornar um array com mais de 3 elementos, então se planeje de acordo.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, mas não entendi muito bem o que ocorreu rs, `regex` nunca foi minha praia. Vou colocar ele no código, melhor que a minha com muita linha rs

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Grosso modo, o PHP saiu percorrendo a string até achar uma substring que casasse com aquele padrão dado no primeiro argumento. Encontrado o padrão, ele dividiu a string em 3 - o que vinha antes, o trecho casado em si, e o que vinha depois. O resultado veio num array.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui também de um jeito mais trivial olhando a documentação do PHP:

```
$str = "senha != over"; // minha string

$arr = str_split($str); //tranformo em array

$c2 = null; //inicio a variavel caracter2 (c2)

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i ++) //percorro meu array
{
    if($arr[$i] == ">" or $arr[$i] == "<" or $arr[$i] == "=") //olho se é igual aos operadores
    {
        $re = $i; //backup da posição do meu array
        $c = $arr[$i] ; // cópia do caracter do operador

        if($arr[$i+1] == ">" or $arr[$i+1] == "<" or $arr[$i+1] == "=") //olho se no próximo indice tenho mais um operador
            $c2 = $arr[$i+1] ; //copio ele para o c2

        break; // paro o for
    }
}
$arrs = explode($arr[$re], $str); //separa meu array em dois, eliminando meu primeiro operador

if($c2 != null) // se tiver ocorrência de dois operadores
    $arrs[1] = str_replace($c2, "", $arrs[1]); // meu segundo array teré o operador apagado

$str = $arrs[0].$c.$c2; //armazeno senha .!.= (. é a concatenação)
$str2 = $arrs[1]; // armazeno o restante no str2 (restante seria over)

 /*ficaria:
$str = "senha !=";
$str2 = " over";
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso é tudo que você deveria fazer:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param type $string A string para cortar
 * @return array Um array com 2 elementos
 */
function smart_split($string) {
    # adidione conforme necessidade
    $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '!=', '>=', '<=');    

    foreach ($operators as $operator) {   
        $operator_found = strpos($string, $operator); 

        if ($operator_found !== false) {
            $operator_with_space_found = strpos($string, $operator . ' ');

            if ( $operator_with_space_found  !== false) {               
                return array(
                    substr($string, 0, $operator_with_space_found + 2),
                    substr($string, $operator_with_space_found + 2));
            } else {
                return array(
                    substr($string, 0, $operator_found + 1),
                    substr($string, $operator_found + 1));
            }
        }      
    }

    return array();     
}
```

Comment: Esses `+2` e `+1` são assim mesmo? Note que alguns operadores têm um único caractere, outros têm dois. Não seria `$operator_with_space_found + strlen($operator) + 1` e `$operator_with_space_found + strlen($operator)`? No mais, boa solução, ainda que restrita a um único espaço após o operador.